# How to disable spell check inside code blocks in markdown?

Tags: spell-checking, filetype-markdown

Code blocks (fenced with ` or ```) are bound to have words not correctly spelled and spell check warnings often get in the way of syntax highlighting. I still want spell check enabled for the rest of my non-code text though.

How can I disable spell-checking just for fenced code blocks.

Comment: The built-in Markdown syntax script doesn't allow spell checking in code blocks. Could you a) provide an example, b) tell us if you use a third-party syntax script?

Comment: I found the same issue is due to treesitter with markdown parser, hightlighting and spellcheck enabled

Comment: While the edit helps, it doesn't address romainl's question: are you using a 3rd-party syntax script?

Comment: This question was asked more than three years ago, closed over a year ago and recently edited with clarifications by another user. I think we can assume OP lost interest in this question. @Kokoro I'd advise you to ask a well-researched question of your own that can be answered.

Answer (score -6):

just go to Setting>>Editor and scroll down the left panel(where you see "General settings" ) and down you'll see "SpellChecker" click on it and uncheck topic of your need and it's it...

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce your solution. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: this sounds like a chatgpt answer :(

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This site is about the Vi and Vim family of editors (see [help/on-topic]), which have no such Settings/Editors/Spell Check menu by default (but do have a spell checking feature). This explains the downvotes and other comments: your answer simply doesn't make sense in the context of the question. If this is indeed a ChatGPT answer, it will be deleted.

Comment: Have we made up our minds whether this is a ChatGPT answer or not? Because even if it isn't, it's certainly not helping anyone. May be time to take out the trash ...